# azure notebooks webservice model lifecycle

Tags: web-services, azure, machine-learning

As stated in title, what is the object lifecycle for the trained model instance in the webservice deployed in Azure Notebook. How long does the trained model persist in memory? Azure web app goes to sleep mode when there is no traffic hitting it. Does it mean that the trained model can become null?

An example of an azure notebook webservice is below
https://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/Notebook/Deployment-of-AzureML-Web-Services-from-Python-Notebooks-4